# How do I stop websites from making my computer look like a proxy server

Tags: windows-10, networking, proxy

I have been banned from a website I use because a third party company they use has me as a 83/100 for possible proxy server. I don't use a VPN or a Proxy. Currently googling about this topic, I can't seem to find something about what would be causing this or I am not asking the right question. I am guessing when I go to websites it in turn sends requests without me knowing it to other locations and thus behind the scenes making it so I look like a proxy. How would I go about stopping all proxy activity on my computer when interacting with the internet so I don't get flagged in the future. Also, how long would it take to be removed from a blacklist or is that forever? Any sites you suggest for better understand what is happen to help me become more knowledgeable to protect myself better in the future? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Need a bit more detail.   What website is it?  What browser are you using?   What OS are you using?   Do you have any custom settings configured in your browser?   Do you have any idea why this website thinks you or browsing it via a proxy?   If you go to https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-http-headers-is-my-browser-sending and post the results, that would be helpful.   That website will capture your browsers HTTP headers (which is what a website sees when you view it in a browser)..

Comment: Thanks for replying. I switched from Chrome to FireFox windows 10. I have the standard settings.The websites I am using a shortlink type sites that have a lot of redirects and pop up windows to earn points from which I think are what is causing my problems. 
ACCEPT  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
ACCEPT-ENCODING  gzip, deflate, br
ACCEPT-LANGUAGE  en-US,en;q=0.5
HOST  www.whatismybrowser.com
TE  trailers
UPGRADE-INSECURE-REQUESTS  1
USER-AGENT  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0

Comment: Not sure if it will let you, but could you edit your original post and include that info?   It is sort of hard to read in a comment.

Comment: Nothing too odd there.    What site are you visiting?  What country do you currently reside in?   It is common practice for system/network admins to block wide ranges of IP addresses if they get attacked from a particular country (China, Russia, etc) on a regular basis.   It might be as simple as that.

Comment: LA USA, The websites are shortlinks which do a lot of popups and redirects a lot. I am doing them for getting points on other sites for getting stuff like some sites where you do tasks for giftcards.

Comment: This should so an image of what the what is my browser showed me https://ibb.co/F6dK0mG

Comment: How about a screenshot of the error from that website?

Comment: This IP address (XX.XX.XX.XX) is a proxy connection and is associated with recent SPAM blacklist activity or abusive behavior. IPQS fraud scoring algorithms have rated this IP address as high risk, scoring 83 out of 100. Users or transactions originating from this IP address should be treated with caution. This decision is based on high confidence due to recent abuse from this connection.

Comment: This implies someone's PC has been hacked and is sending spam. Check all devices on your network with good AV and ask your ISP if your IP address can be changed, or if they can help clean the RBL mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is almost unanswerable - it could be activity from your IP, or other IP addresses in the same range or something else (conceivably reverse DNS)

The solution is to reach out to your ISP and the third party.  If they can't help, and the web provider won't help, and if your ISP is not proxyong your traffic, you are either SOL or will want to get a lawyer involved. I'm not one, but a threat about Interference with Business Relations on a lawyers letterhead to the third party might get you past front-line powerless drones.

Generally your computer needs to be set up as a proxy before it behaves like one or maybe something like a TOR node - it dorsnt just happen. Its also conceivable the remote end is factoring browser strings and changing browser could help but thats unlikely.

Its also possible you are behind CGN (carrier grade NAT) - which yoy would need to discuss with your Internet provider. If your routers WAN IP (or any IP in a trace route) starts with 100.x.x.x that is likely, and you would need your ISPs help or to go to another ISP.

One other possible avenue to consider is rbl blacklists - I found https://www.smartphones.how/internet/how-to-check-ip-vpn-or-proxy-blacklist which might be useful.

Comment: agreed....   It could be a number of things that are causing this  issue for @Distractor

Comment: Thank you for the information. I am sure my questions are not constructed correctly for sure since I am unsure exactly my problem is. The reason I was banned was because of this company: https://www.ipqualityscore.com/free-ip-lookup-proxy-vpn-test/lookup/

Comment: Country  US |||
|||Fraud Score
IP Reputation  83 - High Risk ||||
Fraud Scores are enhanced by passing additional details through our API and CSV batch checks.
||||||Mail SPAM Block List  Blacklisted IP Reported as Blacklisted
||||||||Proxy/VPN Detection  Proxy/VPN Proxy/VPN Detected
|||This IP address appears to be a high risk proxy connection.

Comment: Well there you have it. The IP address your request is coming from has been blacklisted - so its likely not your computer or network.  Its a long shot, but try turning your router off for some hours (ie overnight). There is an outside chance you will get another IP address which will be clean. Otherwise - speak to your ISP.

Comment: It is conceivable you, or another PC on your network has been compromised and sent so - which could get you onto an RBL. Its equally possible someone else did this and you were assigned their IP.

Comment: So, based off of this information, it isn't me but someone used this IP in a way to do something and I will need to contact my ISP to have my IP changed? I unplugged my router for about 5 hours the other night hoping that might work, but it didnt do anything, unless I need to do 8+ hours. But, is it possible when you go to a website for it to send packets to your computer and have your computer send the information off to another address? I guess, I am trying to figure out if it is pop ups ads and such that could be doing this with my computer or something completely out of my control? Thanks.

Comment: Its not pop-up adds, its bad behaviour associated with the IP address your router has. It could be a device on your network has been hacked, or your router has been assigned someone else's bad IP.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will check out with the ISP and check all of my devices and my router. If I am looking at my routers history. Would there be anything I should look for in the logs that would indicate if one of my devices is sending a lot of bad traffic?

Comment: I have malwarebytes and it says everything is clean. Is there a better AV I should look into?

Comment: Its unlikely your router history will show much.  **I'm not much of a Windows user**, but as I understand it, Malwarebytes on its own is not great for AV as its primarily a malware scanner, not a virus one - although there is significant overlap - it should - at minimum - be  used with Windows built in AV. Bit defender may not be a bad choice.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will look into other companies like McAfee as a possible solution. Thanks again for all of your information and help.